# blocking access to internet for subnet

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

[image]

This is my setup. I want to block the access to the internet for a certain subnet ( 192.168.200.X). I still want to be able to access my internal Webserver. I tried blocking the subnet by adding:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.200.0/255.255.255.0 -j DROP
```

But it isn’t working.

Comment: How exactly is it “not working”?

Comment: can still access to the internet

Comment: @amam did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding that to the FORWARD chain rather than INPUT?

[Here is a good starting guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/iptables-inbound-and-outbound-rules)